# Extracting Multiple Quoted Values from String in R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to extract multiple quoted values from a string:

```
{  "What is your license plate number?": "FSD15a",  "What is the color of your car?": "Grey",  "What is the make AND model of your car?": "Hyundai Sonata",  "What are the last three digits of your zip code?": "043",  "What are the last three digits of your phone number?": "681"}
```

Specifically, I would like each of these values (e.g. What is your license plate number?, FSD15a, What is the make AND Model of your car, Hyundai Sonata, etc) to be new columns in the df and have used the following code before to extract just the numbers:

```
df %>% mutate(col1 = str_extract_all(Custom.Fields, "\\d+")) %>%
unnest_wider(c(col1)) %>%
set_names(c(names(df), str_c('col', seq_along(.)[-1])))
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this with quoted values. Any help you could provide would be incredibly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier using `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
as.data.frame(fromJSON(Custom.Fields), check.names = FALSE)
```

-output

```
What is your license plate number? What is the color of your car? What is the make AND model of your car?
1                             FSD15a                           Grey                          Hyundai Sonata
  What are the last three digits of your zip code? What are the last three digits of your phone number?
1                                              043                                                  681
```

---

If there are multiple entries, split between the `}{` and then apply the `fromJSON` by looping

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(strsplit(Custom.Fields, 
   "(?<=\\})\\s+(?=\\{)", perl = TRUE)[[1]], fromJSON))
What.is.your.license.plate.number. What.is.the.color.of.your.car. What.is.the.make.AND.model.of.your.car.
1                                N/A                            N/A                                     N/A
2                             ABC123                          Blue                        Toyota Highlander
  What.are.the.last.three.digits.of.your.zip.code. What.are.the.last.three.digits.of.your.phone.number.
1                                            30127                                                  389
2                                              083                                                  313
```

#### data

```
Custom.Fields <- '{  "What is your license plate number?": "FSD15a",  "What is the color of your car?": "Grey",  "What is the make AND model of your car?": "Hyundai Sonata",  "What are the last three digits of your zip code?": "043",  "What are the last three digits of your phone number?": "681"}
```

Comment: Perfect! (and thanks again- you had the answer a year ago!)

To finish off the code, it would be something like this:

`df %>% mutate(col1 = as.data.frame(fromJSON(df$Custom.Fields), check.names = FALSE)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(c(col1)) %>% 
  set_names(c(names(df), str_c('col', seq_along(.)[-1])))`

Comment: @ChrisWiese I would use `df %>% mutate(col1 = as.data.frame(fromJSON(Custom.Fields), check.names = FALSE)) %>% unpack(col1, names_sep = "_")`

Comment: oh, that is fantastic! Thank you very much for your quick and excellent help!

Comment: As responses started to come in, this code is now giving me "parse error: trailing garbage"

Comment: @ChrisWiese maybe your new responses are  having some format issues i.e. absence of quotes or `{}`

Comment: The data are deviating a bit... 

R1:   {  "What is your license plate number?": "N/A",  "What is the color of your car?": "N/A",  "What is the make AND model of your car?": "N/A",  "What are the last three digits of your zip code?": "30127",  "What are the last three digits of your phone number?": "389"}

R2:{  "What is your license plate number?": "ABC123",  "What is the color of your car?": "Blue ",  "What is the make AND model of your car?": "Toyota Highlander",  "What are the last three digits of your zip code?": "083",  "What are the last three digits of your phone number?": "313"}

Comment: but the `{}` are still there.

Comment: @ChrisWiese try the update

Comment: Thanks again for so quickly replying! When I try to apply that to a df

`df %>% your code` 

I get this error

`Error in do.call(., rbind.data.frame, lapply(strsplit(Custom.Fields, "(?<=\\})\\s+(?=\\{)",  : 
  second argument must be a list`

If I try and modify it using the mutate command:

`df %>% mutate(col1 = your code` 

It uses the first response for every row.

Comment: @ChrisWiese Try `unlist(strsplit(Custom.Fields,...`

Comment: 'df %>% mutate(col1 = do.call(rbind.data.frame, unlist(strsplit(Custom.Fields, 
                                        "(?<=\\})\\s+(?=\\{)", perl = TRUE)[[1]], fromJSON)))'

gives me an error too:

Caused by error in `do.call()`:
! second argument must be a list

Comment: @ChrisWiese you can change it to `as.list(unlist(..`

Comment: That runs with no errors, but it just creates a new column (with an unwieldy name) and copies the responses to that column.

Comment: @ChrisWiese can you show few rows of your data with dput

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245896/discussion-between-chris-wiese-and-akrun).